# What values of $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ does $\phi =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} : ax+by=6\}$ define a function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

What values of $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ does $\phi = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} : ax+by=6\}$ define a function?

Maybe I'm interpreting this question wrong, but it doesn't seem like any values of $a$ and $b$ will make this a function, because for any $a,b$ that works for a particular $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ then it won't work for $x+1$ or $y+1$ won't satisfy $a(x+1)+b(y+1)=6$ and is therefore not a function

Comment: If $b=1,$ then it's easily a function.  Do you see why your argument doesn't work in that case?

Comment: Not particularly. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hint: Consider [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity).

Comment: Maybe I'm interpreting it wrong. I interpret this as an equation s.t. there exists an a and b s.t. for any x and y that are integers then ax+by=6. Which I don't think that exists.

Comment: "For any integer $x$, there exists one and only one integer $y$ such that $ax+by=6$" is how you should interpret it.  In this case, as long as $b\neq 0$, there will always be at most one $y$-value given any $x$-value; therefore, we're really interested in whether there will always be a $y$-value.

Comment: So a=0, b=1 and y=6 would be the solution?

Comment: If $0\in\Bbb N$ then $a=b=0$ define the empty function. If $a=0$ then $y=\frac6b$ is a (constant) function when $b|6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $x=0.$  Then the equation becomes $by = 6,$ and since $b,y$ are assumed to be integers (with $b\geq 0$) we find that $b$ must be one of the divisors of $6$: $1, 2, 3, 6.$

Set $x=1.$  Then the equation becomes $a + by = 6 \implies a = 6 - by$ and since $b$ is a divisor of the right-hand side for any integer $y,$ we conclude $b$ divides $a,$ and write $a = bk$ for some integer $k.$

Using this to re-write the equation, $$bkx + by = 6 \iff y = \frac{6}{b} - kx$$ which is a unique integer for any integer $x.$

We conclude that the given relation $\phi$ is a function for any $b \in \{1,2,3,6\}$ and any $a \in b\mathbb{N},$ and for no other values of $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: $y=f(x)=\frac{6-ax}b$. When $x=0$ then $y=\frac6b$ so $b$ divides $6$, and $y=\frac6b-\frac{ax}b$. When $x=1$ then $y=\frac6b-\frac ab$, and since $\frac6b$ is an integer it follows that $\frac ab$ is an integer so $b$ divides $a$. Just clarifying to myself your answer.